# Emacs: number-or-marker-p error

Tags: emacs, error-handling, dired, icicles

Some times when I mess up with icicles, dired, sunrise commander or some other guy -

```
number-or-marker-p
```

error pops up - and it nearly blocks emacs - no `query-find-replace` works, no `ido` any more. The only way - is to restart emacs. Does any body have a way to make emacs forget this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should it do instead of issuing an error?  Let's say you try `M-x query-find-replace` and this error happens.  Should the operation just silently do nothing?  At least with the error you know that something has gone wrong.

Either stop what you're doing that is breaking things, or fix (get it fixed) the underlying problem.

To start the process of fixing the bug, try setting [`debug-on-error`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html) to `t`, triggering the error and looking at the stack trace.  Or add this to your .emacs:

```lisp
(setq debug-on-error t)
```

Update the question with the backtrace and start again...